# WCF Data Service Blowing Up - Very Heavy Payloads - Anyway to avoid all the clutter?

Tags: xml, silverlight, web-services, wcf-data-services, odata

I am using WCF Data Services (v2) and my Entity Model has grown quite a bit over time, i.e. over 100 entities.  There is quite a bit of navigation that is possible.  The client UIs are LOB applications with data entry and search screens.  The search forms bring back collections of data and the data entry forms usually comprise of ONE entity that has the majority of the properties but with MANY navigation properties due to comboboxes needed to display these individual collections (e.g. an Employee data entry form with ComboBoxes displaying a State list or Department list.  I lazy load the combobox data FYI.

The issue I am having is that if I want to populate a simple list (via a ComboBox), the payload is HUMONGOUS!  Using fiddler, e.g., the XML generated has a bunch of clutter that I don't really NEED just to populate this ComboBox.

Here is an example of ONE record being brought back of type Employee.

```
   ----------------------------- 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://localhost/HumanResourcesService.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Employees</title>
  <id>http://localhost/HumanResourcesService.svc/Employees</id>
  <updated>2011-11-09T23:41:01Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Employees" href="Employees" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://localhost/HumanResourcesService.svc/Employees('54924')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2011-11-09T23:41:01Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Employee" href="Employees('54924')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/EmployeeTypes" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="EmployeeTypes" href="Employees('54924')/EmployeeTypes" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Locations" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Locations" href="Employees('54924')/Locations" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Buildings" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Buildings" href="Employees('54924')/Buildings" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Managers" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Managers" href="Employees('54924')/Managers" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Assignments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Assignments" href="Employees('54924')/Assignments" />
    // ********************************************
    // MANY MORE LINKS - REMOVED FOR BREVITY
    // ********************************************        
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/xxx" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="xxx" href="Employees('54924')/xxx" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/yyy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="yyy" href="Employees('54924')/yyy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/zzz" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="zzz" href="Employees('54924')/zzz" />
    <category term="xxx.HumanResources.Employee" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:EmpNo m:type="Edm.String">54924</d:EmpNo>
        <d:FirstName m:type="Edm.String">John</d:FirstName>
        <d:LastName m:type="Edm.String">Hughes</d:LastName>
        <d:MiddleName m:type="Edm.String">Michael</d:MiddleName>
        <d:Salary m:type="Edm.Decimal">20000</d:Salary>
        <d:Notes m:type="Edm.String">Anything...</d:Notes>
        <d:PrimaryPhone m:type="Edm.String">984-875-4545</d:PrimaryPhone>
        <d:StartDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">1977-02-01T00:00:00</d:StartDate>
        <d:EndDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">1995-12-31T00:00:00</d:EndDate>
        // ********************************************
        // MANY MORE PROPERTIES - REMOVED FOR BREVITY
        // ********************************************
        <d:AnotherFieldX m:type="Edm.Double" m:null="true" />
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>

-----------------------------
```

As you can see, I don't need all that junk like those LINKS and this is just ONE entity.  All of these ComboBoxes are bound to many entities (ranging anywhere from about 10 to 1000s of records).  As you can imagine, all this extra "chatter" can quickly blow up my service. All I want is to display a collection of Employee Names in this case (many similar cases for ComboBoxes).

Has anyone tackled this convoluted scenario?  I am seeking some recommendations.

Comment: What do you mean, “blow up”? Are you getting some error? Or is it just slow?

Comment: @svick: Not error.  By "blowing up", I am referring to the sheer size of some these payloads.  For example, if I just bring back a list of 20 objects, the XML generated is HUGE.  As a starting point, I would like to find a way to not include all those links.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Links aren't serialized if you use $select:

- [http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?$top=1&$select=Name](http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?%24top=1&%24select=Name) → no links
- [http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?$top=1](http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?%24top=1) → including links

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JSON as opposed to XML? The formatting of JSON is inherently leaner. You can also (as others suggested) use the $select= Query option to limit the fields that are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $select query option to project only the fields you are interested in. In your case, if you add $select=FirstName, LastName, you won't see all the other fields you don't need.

Check out [the documentation](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#SelectSystemQueryOption) for more details. I don't recall whether links are still serialized if you do a projection, so you may still have that overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yes, I'm sorry for my initial post leaving out a couple of key points, but I actually do use constructs like: .Select(i => i.FirstName, i => i.LastName) in my IQueryables.  Would you agree that including all these unneeded links could add to the payload of a "simple" service?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have all the entity sets in your data model exposed by your OData service?

If you expose only the entity sets that you need (by [calling SetEntitySetAccessRule once for each entity set that you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358710.aspx)), you won't get a `rel` link generated for any entities not exposed by the data service.

On the other hand, if you need all of those related entities in your unit of work, it might be that your data model is over-normalized, and you could consider denormalizing it a bit. If you are already using `$select` to reduce the size of entity property data, this might generate less overall XML, but I am only guessing about this and you would need to test it.

Of course, (as Leon suggested) JSON is the most efficient wire format for OData, but the WCF Data Services client libraries don't yet support JSON.